# Occasional token not found for Generic Webhook Trigger Jenkins Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, webhooks, github-webhook

We have a lot of jenkins jobs set up as webhook endpoints using Generic Webhook Trigger.

It's mostly working fine. With the token, it's able to find the specific Jenkins job to run for each webhook event.

However occasionally we hit a 404 error with below error message:

```
{"jobs":null,"message":"Did not find any jobs with GenericTrigger configured! If you are using a 
token, you need to pass it like ...trigger/invoke?token=TOKENHERE. If you are not using a token, 
you need to authenticate like http://user:passsword@jenkins/generic-webhook... "}
```

Wondering if there is any reason for this behavior? Is it because of how Generic Webhook Trigger's tokens are mapped, maybe it's getting reset once in a while due to some events? We are hitting a scalability bottleneck due to this issue and would love some insights. Thanks ahead!

[image]